# Polymer 1.0 populate paper-menu with original styling

Tags: polymer-1.0

Styling noob question: can I make an element that populates a paper-menu that inherits the parents original styling?

Starting point: Polymer starter kit.
in the index.html file there is a paper-menu that looks like this;

```
<paper-menu class="list" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}" on-iron-select="onMenuSelect">
                <a data-route="home" href="/"   >
                    <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
</paper-menu>
```

Everything is styled fine and vertical.

I decided to create my own element that pulls this menu items from an ajax request.

```
<dom-module id="my-sidebar">
<style>

</style>
<template>
    <iron-ajax id="menuAjax" params="{{menuParams}}" on-response="handleResponse" handle-as="json" last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ajaxResponse.main}}">
                <a data-route="{{item.data-route}}" href="{{item.href}}">
                    <iron-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></iron-icon>
                    <span>{{item.label}}</span>
                </a>
            </template>
</template>

<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-sidebar',
            properties: {

                ajaxResponse: {},
                url: {
                    type: String
                },
                menuParams: {}
            },
            ready: function () {
                this.url = "/json/sidebar-menu.json";
                this.$.menuAjax.url = this.url;
                this.$.menuAjax.generateRequest();
                this.$.menuAjax.auto = true;
                console.log("my-sidebar is ready");
            },
            handleResponse: function (request) {
                console.log("response recieved");
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

This element works and does pull the correct json, however the styling is nowhere close to the original vertical menu items.

My new paper menu looks like this.

```
<paper-menu class="list" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}" on-iron-select="onMenuSelect">
             <my-sidebar></my-sidebar>
</paper-menu>
```

The menus show up horizontally, different fonts, etc.

Answer (score 2):

What I've found to help with maintaining the style for font and padding is to include style information from app->styles->app-theme.html into the  tags within the  tags following examples here (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html).